# How to quickly download all GMTED2010 data?

Tags: data, elevation

Is there a way to automatically download all the tiles in GMTED2010 data?
From:

https://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED_viewer/viewer.htm

I can only seem to be able to download by double-clicking tile by tile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Ana! What about downloading the zipped [GMTED2010 Global Grids](https://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/gmted2010_global_grids.php)?

Answer (score 3):

This is the web directory where the data is stored for their webapp.

https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/topo/downloads/GMTED/

There is a directory that has zip files for the grids
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google Earth Engine account, you can download it all in one go.

```
var GMTED = ee.Image('USGS/GMTED2010')
var globe = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-180, 88, 0, 88, 180, 88, 180, -88, 0, -88, -180, -88], null, false)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: GMTED,
  description: 'gmted',
  folder: 'gmted',
  region: globe,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

This will put it in your linked Google Drive account in a folder called 'gmted'. I'm not sure what resolution it will export at--you can add a scale: resolution_in_meters option to the export to specify.

Comment: Which values of elevation does this provide? It only seems to be a single layer to me

Comment: If you read the docs, it says "The version of the dataset available here is Breakline Emphasis, 7.5 arc-seconds resolution."

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP files shown in a previous comment are ArcGIS format rasters. If you want geotiffs, you'll need to use EarthExplorer to find the tiles you want, select them for bulk download, then run USGS's bulk download tool.

Earth Explorer: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Bulk Download Instructions: https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/ee_help

Comment: The help link doesn't appear to work any more